# True or false statement about a simple limit of product

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to determine whether the following statement is true or not:

> Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two sequences such that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_nb_n)=0$$ then either $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=0$
>   or $\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n)=0$

It seems like the statement is true and I can't find any counterexample for it. But for some reason I fail to prove it (the standard product rule doesn't work here because we know nothing about the convergence of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$). I'd appreciate any ideas on how to prove it.

Comment: @Dr.MV - looks like the statement is false (see Timbuc example).

Comment: If you add the requirement that both limits $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ have to exist then the statement becomes true.

Comment: @Winther - What if we know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n)=1$? Can we say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=0$?

Comment: Yes since $a_n = \frac{a_nb_n}{b_n}$ so $\lim a_n = \frac{\lim a_nb_n}{\lim b_n} = \frac{0}{1} = 0 $

Comment: @Winther - brilliant, sir. Thank you.

Comment: @Winther If you add the requirement that *either* of the limits exist, the statement is true.

Comment: @Winther - what if $c>0$, and for all but a finite number of terms $b_n\geq c$. Can we say then that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=0$?

Comment: @Winther - I think it is true because $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_nb_n)=0\Rightarrow\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N,\forall n>N:|a_nb_n|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow|a_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{b_n}\Rightarrow|a_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{c}\Rightarrow\\\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$
Am I correct?

Comment: @trfv Yes that is also correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

Take

$$\{a_n\}=\{0,1,0,1,0,\ldots\}\;\;,\;\;\;\;\{b_n\}=\{1,0,1,0,1\,\ldots\}$$

Comment: Oh, gosh, you made me feel so stupid. Thank you!

Comment: $\{\}$ is used for sets, so you're saying $\{a_n\}=\{0,1\}$. Overall this seems like abuse of notation. Maybe it should be denoted with $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb Z^+}=(0,1,0,1,\ldots)$.

Comment: @user31415 Many authors agree with the notation I use: $\;\{a_n\}\;$ meaning: the sequence (which is a set) with elements $\;\{a_1,a_2,..,a_n,...\}\;$, and in $\;\{a_n\}=\{0,1,0,1,\ldots\}\;$ the meaning is the elements are *numbered*. You can check the books by Purcell-Varberg, Thomas, Thomas-Finney, Stewart, Swokowski, Spivak, etc. The meaning is usually pretty clear from the context.

Comment: What if for all but a finite number of terms $b_n\geq c, c>0$? Can we say then that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=0$? (see my reasoning in the comments above)

Comment: @trfv Yes, I think that's correct.